# Hibernate detached criteria issue

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I am trying to execute the following query using hibernate criteria. But, it is not giving me correct results.

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TableA a 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   TableB b 
               WHERE  b.col1 = a.col1 
                      AND b.flag = 'Y');
```

Hibernate:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TableA.class, "a");
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TableB.class, "b");
dc.add(Property.forName("b.col1").eqProperty("a.col1"));

dc.add(Restrictions.eq("b.flag","Y"));
dc.setProjection(Property.forName("b.col1"));

criteria.add(Subqueries.notExists(dc));
```

---

The query it is generating is-

```
select * from TableA a where not exists (select b.col1 from TableB b where **b.col1=b.col1** and b.flag='Y');
```

Here, I am not sure why it is comparing b.col1 with b.col1.

Can someone please help in fixing this issue. Thanks in advance.

--
Teja.

Comment: TableA is distinct to TableB? I generated your example with tableA distinct to TableB and the query generated is this:select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.nombre as nombre0_0_, this_.activo as activo0_0_ 
from prueba.Actividad this_ 
where not exists (
 select b_.activo as y0_ 
 from prueba.Cargo b_ 
 where this_.nombre=b_.nombre and b_.activo=?)